# How to speed up the processing of a VBA script using a web site?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script that allows me to calculate the distance in kms between two cities:
[image]

This script works correctly, the problem is that the list of cities to calculate that I was given is more than 5000 cities.

When I press the "GO" button, the processing starts and the Excel file freezes and it is impossible to see the progress of the processing until it is finished and it takes almost 1 hour...

Is it possible to improve the processing speed of my script or is it due to the speed of my internet connection?

And from about 3000 cities the script stops because the processing is too long. How can I solve this ?

```
Option Explicit

Public Const DIST = "http://www.distance2villes.com/recherche?source="


Sub Distance()
Dim lg As Integer, i As Integer
Dim Url As String, Txt As String

    With Sheets("Feuil1")
        lg = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lg
            Url = DIST & .Range("A" & i).Value & "&destination=" & .Range("B" & i).Value
            With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
                .Open "GET", Url, False
                .send
                Txt = .responseText
            End With
            
            ' Only set the value if we got a response
            If Txt <> vbNullString Then .Range("C" & i).Value = Split(Split(Txt, "id=""distanciaRuta"">")(1), "</strong>")(0)

            ' Clear our variable before next
            Txt = vbNullString
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It's probably just the server response time rather than connection speed. You can display progress with `If i mod 10 = 0 Then Application.statusbar = i & " of " & lg`. Do you need to run macro more than once.?

Comment: Where should I put this line in my code? No, I just have to run the macro once so that all distances are calculated. But I have to do it in two parts because after 3000 cities the script crashes

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try. But it depends on the speed of the server, I can't do much to speed up this processing?

Comment: You might be able to eke out a little more performance by using early binding: add a reference to **Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1** and `With New WinHttpRequest ... End With`. Also you might want to consider inserting a `DoEvents` statement at the end of the loop, or perhaps after every 10 or 100 iterations. Also, once you get to these kinds of numbers, you are currently iterating over every row; a better option might be to load the entire range into an array and loop over that instead.

Comment: I just noticed you are creating new Winhttp object for each request. I think you can reuse the same one if you create it outside the loop.

Comment: So I create a reference to Microsoft WinHTTP Services before my for loop and I replace my line `With CreateObject... ` by `With New WinHttpRequest` ?

Comment: `Set obj = CreateObject(...) and then With obj ... I am on a tablet so I can't test it.

Comment: Currently I checked Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1 in the references and I changed `With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")` by `With New WinHttpRequest`

Comment: You should probably write `Dim obj As WinHttpRequest` and the next line, `Set WinHttpRequest = New WinHttpRequest`.

Comment: What level should I put the second line at? @ZevSpitz

Comment: Right after the `Dim ...`.

Comment: I have an execution error when I put them under each other

Comment: On the `Set... line`? Or later? What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: When I run the macro I get an error that highlights `WinHttpRequest` on the line Set WinHttpRequest = New WinHttpRequest  and says "compilation error: variable not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229870/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-patrick62).

Comment: You can run in asynchronous mode, which allows you to run multiple calls at the same time, which would (in theory) allow you to process the whole list more quickly - see for example http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### GetElementById (vs Double-Split)

- The problem here is that the website is generating huge web pages somehow dependent on the distance between the cities e.g. Paris-London generates a string of about 90k characters, while Paris-Vladivostok 1.4M characters.
- Using a different object (`MSXML2.XMLHTTP`) increased the efficiency by about 10%.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Distance()
    
    Const DIST1 As String = "http://www.distance2villes.com/recherche?source="
    Const DIST2 As String = "&destination="
    Const DIST3 As String = "distanciaRuta"
    Const wsName As String = "Feuil1"
    
    'Dim w As Object: Set w = CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    Dim w As Object: Set w = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Dim h As Object: Set h = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(, 1))
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim isFound As Boolean: isFound = True
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Url As String
    Dim S As String
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Len(Data(i, 1)) > 0 And Len(Data(i, 2)) > 0 Then
            Url = DIST1 & Data(i, 1) & DIST2 & Data(i, 2)
            w.Open "GET", Url, False
            w.Send
            h.body.innerHTML = w.responseText
            On Error GoTo NotFoundError
            S = h.getElementById(DIST3).innerText
            On Error GoTo 0
            If isFound Then
                Data(i, 1) = Replace(Left(S, Len(S) - 3), ",", "")
            Else
                Data(i, 1) = ""
                isFound = True
            End If
        Else
            Data(i, 1) = ""
        End If
    Next
    rg.Columns(1).Offset(, 2).Value = Data
    
    Exit Sub

NotFoundError:
    isFound = False
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanations, did you use the same columns as me? When I want to execute your macro I have an error that says "variable not defined" for the variable `sData` here: `Data(i, 1) = Replace(Left(S, Len(sData) - 3), ",", "") `

Comment: Sorry, replace `sData` with `S`. That was a last-minute change.

Comment: Oh thanks I just tried it on a lot of cities indeed it is much faster! Is it possible to add after the calculation of distances "km" as on my first script in the column for display?

Comment: Just remove the stuff around `S`: `Data(i, 1) = S`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, it's much faster!

Comment: And last question, when you say 10% you tried with many cities?

Comment: With a hundred. But you must also consider the `GetElementById`. You could try to use your double-split solution instead of the line `S = h.getElementById(DIST3).innerText` e.g.: `S = Split(Split(w.responseText, "id=""distanciaRuta"">")(1), "</strong>")(0)` to see what exactly increased the speed.

Comment: Perfect thank you I will try. But with more than 1000 cities it is much faster.

Comment: Hello @VBasic2008, I have used your script for several days and it works great and fast. However, I sometimes had problems because cities can have the same name in different countries of the world. Do you think we can add a third column with the country in which to search? Do you know a VBA script that can do the same thing with the specified country?

Comment: Sorry, I was over my head already. VBA is what I understand but my knowledge in scraping is less than basic. Try to ask another question and post this code and explain what's wrong. There are some true wizards here who can figure it out. Add some sample data including the cities and their countries.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. Yes I will do that I think it's the best for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try reusing request object (Untested)

```vb
Sub Distance()
    Dim lg As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim Url As String, Txt As String
    Dim objReq as WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest
    Set objReq = new WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest

    With Sheets("Feuil1")
        lg = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lg
            If i Mod 10 = 0 Then Application.Statusbar = i & " of " & lg
            Url = DIST & .Range("A" & i).Value & "&destination =" & .Range("B" & i).Value
            With objReq
                .Open "GET", Url, False
                .send
                Txt = .responseText
            End With
            
            ' Only set the value if we got a response
            If Txt <> vbNullString Then .Range("C" & i).Value = Split(Split(Txt, "id=""distanciaRuta"">")(1), "</strong>")(0)

            ' Clear our variable before next
            Txt = vbNullString
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @patrick What was the error ? Try adding HTTPWIN - see update.

Comment: Same thing, I have the script that starts but runs in a vacuum and the distances don't start

Answer (score 1):

You can run in asynchronous mode, which allows you to run multiple calls at the same time, which would (in theory) allow you to process the whole list more quickly - see for example

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/

As a quick example:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Const DIST = "http://www.distance2villes.com/recherche?source="

Dim requests As Collection

Sub Distance()
    Dim i As Long, r
    
    r = Rnd() ' "cachebuster" for testing...

    Set requests = New Collection
    With Sheets("Data")
        For i = 2 To 13
            .Range("C" & i).Value = "Waiting"
            SendRequest i, DIST & .Range("A" & i).Value & _
                           "&destination=" & .Range("B" & i).Value & "&v=" & r
        Next i
    End With

End Sub

'create a request object and matching handler,
'  add the handler to the "requests" collection,
'  send the request
Sub SendRequest(rowNum As Long, URL As String)
    Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim handler As New asyncHandler
    handler.rowNum = rowNum          'store the row number for the request
    handler.Initialize req
    req.OnReadyStateChange = handler
    req.Open "GET", URL, True
    requests.Add handler, (CStr("Row" & rowNum))
    req.send
End Sub

'called from each instance of `handler` as it completes
Sub SetResult(txt, rowNum)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(rowNum, "C").Value = txt
    requests.Remove CStr("Row" & rowNum)
    Debug.Print "requests queue - " & requests.count
End Sub
```

"Handler" class `asyncHandler` (see link for extra step required with this):

```vb
Option Explicit

Public rowNum As Long

Dim m_xmlHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
 
Public Sub Initialize(ByRef xmlHttpRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP)
   Set m_xmlHttp = xmlHttpRequest
End Sub
 
Sub OnReadyStateChange()
    Dim v
    If m_xmlHttp.readyState = 4 Then
        If m_xmlHttp.Status = 200 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            v = Split(Split(m_xmlHttp.responseText, _
                            "id=""distanciaRuta"">")(1), "</strong>")(0)
            On Error GoTo 0
            SetResult v, rowNum 'update the sheet
        Else
            SetResult m_xmlHttp.statusText, rowNum
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so if I understand correctly, I put your script in the macro and in the module part I create a module with the name `asyncHandler` and I put your second code?

Comment: `asyncHandler` is a Class Module, not a regular module, and you need to follow the instructions in the link on exporting it, modifying and then re-importing it